# How in the method of POST, save the value of the variable of the Django class

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

How in the method of POST, save the value of the variable of the Django class. There is a select on the form, when selecting a value, the valuation needs to be saved to a variable and reload the page, already with the saved data.

```
class MovementsListView(TemplateView, CurrentURLMixin):
  allow_empty = True
  template_name = "movement_index.html"
  accounts = None
  info_account = None
  case_account = None

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  self.accounts = Account.objects.all()
  print(self.case_account) # !!!print always - None, it's necessary - 1
  self.info_account = Account.objects.filter(account_code=self.case_account)
  return super(MovementsListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(MovementsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context["accounts"] = self.accounts
  context["info_account"] = self.info_account
  return context

#Get case_account
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  self.case_account = request.POST["case_account"]
  print(self.case_account) # !!!print example - 1
  return redirect("movement_index")
```

Comment: is this the original indentation of your code? all the functions should be indented one level to make them methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You must not save data to instance attributes on a class-based view. If this worked, it would cause horrible thread safety issues, allowing all users to see the last value that was saved. This is why Django does a huge amount behind the scenes to make it impossible.

The place to store user-specific data between requests is the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/).